# Can't see install option for React PWA on Chrome on Kindle

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, kindle-fire

I created a React PWA with this tutorial: [pwa react tutorial](https://medium.com/@toricpope/transform-a-react-app-into-a-progressive-web-app-pwa-dea336bd96e6)

I added some Add to Homescreen code I got from here: [Add to Homescreen tut](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners)

I want to test downloading the app, but I can't see the Chrome install link on the url. I see a download link on Kindle, but not the install link I see on Chrome on my laptop.

My code is here: [git repo](https://github.com/DavTho1983/pwa-test)

My goal is to install on a Kindle and have an icon on the Home Screen that I click to launch the app.

Comment: What browser are you using there? It may not support a PWA.

Comment: I have a chrome apk installed on the Kindle Fire?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could use Chrome on a kindle tablet. Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: Yeah it passes fine